# How fill a regex string with parameters

Tags: python, regex, django, string

I would like to fill regex variables with string.

```
import re

hReg = re.compile("/robert/(?P<action>([a-zA-Z0-9]*))/$")
hMatch = hReg.match("/robert/delete/")
args = hMatch.groupdict()
```

args variable is now a dict with {"action":"delete"}.

How i can reverse this process ?  With args dict and regex pattern, how i can obtain the string "/robert/delete/" ?

it's possible to have a function just like this ?

```
def reverse(pattern, dictArgs):
```

Thank you

Comment: If you have a dictionary of values that describe your string to the extend that you're interested in it...  Why would you need a regex to re-build that string? You already have all the bits that make a difference. Simply write a function that takes those bits and creates a string. (In other words, no this is not possible and you probably waste your time trying.)

Comment: I would like this "feature" to implement a function like reverse() used in Django to get an URL string. It's possible Django just "brute-force" pattern with args ?

Comment: If at all, it's a Python thing, not a Django thing. But my point is this. How would you reverse, for example, `"/robe[or]t?/(?P<action>((?!foo)[a-zA-Z0-9]*))"`? There is no way to go from a list of matches back to the original string because the regex contains optional and conditional parts that depend on each other. So either you define an *extremely* narrow sub-set of regex that is allowed and write a parser for that, probably still missing some side-cases and severely limiting yourself - or you spend your time more productively. ;) Regex matching is a one-way street.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function should do it

```
def reverse(regex, dict):
    replacer_regex = re.compile('''
        \(\?P\<         # Match the opening
            (.+?)       # Match the group name into group 1
        \>\(.*?\)\)     # Match the rest
        '''
        , re.VERBOSE)

    return replacer_regex.sub(lambda m : dict[m.group(1)], regex)
```

You basically match the (\?P...) block and replace it with a value from the dict.

EDIT: regex is the regex string in my exmple. You can get it from patter by

```
regex_compiled.pattern
```

EDIT2: verbose regex added

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i thinks it's doable for some narrow cases, but pretty complex thing "in general case".

You'll need to write some sort of finite state machine, parsing your regex string, and splitting different parts, then take appropriate action for this parts.

For regular symbols — simply put symbols "as is" into results string. 
For named groups — put values from dictArgs in place of them
For optional blocks — put some of it's values

And so on.

One requllar expression often can match big (or even infinite) set of strings, so this "reverse" function wouldn't be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @Dimitri's answer, more sanitisation is possible.

```
retype = type(re.compile('hello, world'))
def reverse(ptn, dict):
    if isinstance(ptn, retype):
        ptn = ptn.pattern
    ptn = ptn.replace(r'\.','.')
    replacer_regex = re.compile(r'''
        \(\?P         # Match the opening
        \<(.+?)\>
        (.*?)
        \)     # Match the rest
        '''
        , re.VERBOSE)
#     return replacer_regex.findall(ptn)
    res = replacer_regex.sub( lambda m : dict[m.group(1)], ptn)
    return res
```